# Calculated Column validation accept a specific character and numbers only

Tags: excel, validation, sharepoint, calculated-columns

So far I manage to make a validation that makes the column only accept numbers:

=ISNUMBER([Column_Name]+0)

But I want users to be able to type ";" inside as column value so only numbers and semicolon allowed.

Anyone have any idea how I can manage that?

Comment: `=OR(G19=";",ISNUMBER(G19+0))`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman does not work beacuse semicolon can be inbetween numbers so "321313;231312" does not work, which it should

Comment: you will probably need a custom VBA validation to ensure this. I don't regular data validation can support this.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I managed it!

Comment: then, please share your solution so others know going forward. it's a bit of interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(";";[Column_Name]));ISNUMBER([Column_Name]+0))
```

Basicly `FIND()` will look for characters in the column and `ISNUMBER()` will be determine of FINDS true/false.

- Column will accepts both numbers and ";".

Comment: keep in mind this will accept `abc;` or anything with as long as the `;` exists.